# Deploying react projects on gh-pages, but page doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my react projects on my GitHub pages ([gh-pages branch](https://github.com/marukohua/portfolio/tree/gh-pages)). 
But [my GitHub page](https://marukohua.github.io/portfolio/) doesn't update.

This is my `package.json`:

```
...,
"homepage': "https://marukohua.github.io/portfolio/",
"dependencies": {
  ... 
},
"scripts": { 
  "deploy": "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build"
},
...
```

I thought that it was possible in my router path. So I use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in my route path. But my page is the same as before.

This is my route path:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`}
      exact
      component={ProjectsPage}
    />
    <Route 
      path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/about`} 
      component={AboutPage} />
    <Route
      path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/projects`}
      component={ProjectsPage}
    />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I created a new project and a new repo on GitHub. Redeploy the project, it works.